# Using mciSendString with spaces

Tags: c, mcisendstring

i am trying to play a sound file with spaces in its name

example: "my File.wav"

So sending files like this:

`mciSendString("play C:\\myFile.wav",0,0,0);`

will work just fine. but:

```
mciSendString("play C:\\my File.wav",0,0,0);
```

will fail.

is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: On Windows, wrap paths containing spaces with quotation marks: `mciSendString("play \"C:\\my File.wav\"",0,0,0);`.

Comment: Posted this as an answer, as I didn't have time to do this yesterday. I am glad it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, paths containing white characters must be wrapped with quotation marks. So instead of:

```
mciSendString("play C:\\my File.wav", 0, 0, 0);
```

write this:

```
mciSendString("play \"C:\\my File.wav\"", 0, 0, 0);
```

That should work.